# How to set Tag Property of a Picture Box at run time

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to set the tag property of a Picture Box Dynamically.
some thing like this

```
tableLayoutPanel1.GetControlFromPosition(c, r).Tag = 1;
```

But later when i am comparing like

```
 if(Convert.ToInt32(pb.Tag.ToString())==1)
```

it show an run time error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

**EDIT**
Got the SOLUTION:-
 The problem was i am not changing the correct picture box `Tag` value.ie the c,r values are wrong.Every thing else work fine when given the correct c,r values.

Comment: Whats wrong with what you just wrote?

Comment: its not setting the tag=1

Comment: What happens? Do you get an error? What do you see in the debugger?

Comment: @SLaks NO later when i am comparing it in a if condition like if(Convert.ToInt32(pb.Tag.ToString())==1) its gives an runtime error   Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET Can u Help??

Comment: Well what's null? the tag property? Are you sure its the same control? Still not enough information to answer.

Comment: Try to see the value of `pb.Tag.ToString()`, I'm sure it contains something that is not an integer

Comment: Put a breakpoint in there and check what pb.Tag contains before you try and convert it.

Comment: So pb is not at position c,r. your use of tag is not the problem..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible that you are setting the `Tag` to wrong control or instance, not to the `pb` picturebox. The `Object reference not set to an instance of an object`-error occurs when you try to read the `Tag` of `pb` and it has never been set.

You can test if the first line is actually using a `PictureBox`-control:

```
((PictureBox)tableLayoutPanel1.GetControlFromPosition(c, r)).Tag = 1;
```

This will make a cast exception error, if the `GetControlFromPosition()`-method's return wasn't a `PictureBox`. If it doesn't, you're probably using a wrong instance.

Answer (score 0):

A silly solution that may solve your problem:

```
 public int AbsoluteValue (String Input) {
    String Temp = String.Empty;
    for (int i = 0; i < Input.Lenght; i++) {
        if (isDigit(Input[i]))
            Temp += Input[i]; 
    }
    return int.Parse(Temp);
 }

 public Boolean isDigit (char c) {
    try {
         int.Parse(c.ToString());
         return true;
    }
    catch (Exception) {
          return false;
    }
 }
```

And then you can

```
  if(AbsoluteValue(pb.Tag.ToString())==1)
```

Keep in mind, using Regex for validating integers is both a lot faster and more reasonable, I just wrote this answer to show you how to do it the low level way.